# Python: SyntaxError: invalid syntax on "for"

Tags: python, syntax

I get this error message when I try to compile my code in Python.  It seems as if it does not like my "for".

```
File "flow.py", line 74

strat_improvements = {strategy: 0 for strategy in STRATEGIES}

                                    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

can someone tell me why this is? I'm relatively new to Python.  Here is a code block...

```
def solve(data):
    """Solves an instance of the flow shop scheduling problem"""

    # We initialize the strategies here to avoid cyclic import issues                                                                                                                               
    initialize_strategies()
    global STRATEGIES

    # Record the following for each strategy:                                                                                                                                                       
    #  improvements: The amount a solution was improved by this strategy                                                                                                                            
    #  time_spent: The amount of time spent on the strategy                                                                                                                                         
    #  weights: The weights that correspond to how good a strategy is                                                                                                                               
    #  usage: The number of times we use a strategy                                                                                                                                                 
    strat_improvements = {strategy:
                          0 for strategy in STRATEGIES}
    strat_time_spent = {strategy: 0 for strategy in STRATEGIES}
    strat_weights = {strategy: 1 for strategy in STRATEGIES}
    strat_usage = {strategy: 0 for strategy in STRATEGIES}

    # Start with a random permutation of the jobs                                                                                                                                                   
    perm = range(len(data))
    random.shuffle(perm)

    # Keep track of the best solution                                                                                                                                                               
    best_make = makespan(data, perm)
    best_perm = perm
    res = best_make
```

Comment: what version of python are you using? it works fine on my computer

Comment: As @rassar is pointing out, this will fail for python2.6 or earlier.  Also, you might want to consider using `dict.fromkeys`:  `strat_improvements = dict.fromkeys(STRATEGIES, 0)`.  It'll likely perform better, is shorter to write and it'll work on much older python versions if that's a constraint...

Comment: Just never use `fromkeys` with a mutable value.